# Filter rows by Buttons extension

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, button, datatables

I have table filled by `json` - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jezrael/z4hurz2n/3/).

I need filter rows by custom button with Buttons extension - show rows with value `dokonané` in column `c12`. Next button show all rows and it works well.

html:

```
<button id="filter">Outside - filter</button>
<button id="filter1">Outside - reload</button>
<table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>c06</th>
          ...
          <th>c12</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

js:

```
table =  $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "link",
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        dom: 'Bt',
        buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Buttons - filter',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {

               //function for filtering

            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Buttons - reload',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }            
       ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "c06" },
            ...
            { "data": "c12" }
        ]
    } );
```

I can filter it by outside buttons with text `Outside - filter`(not generated by extension):

```
$("#filter").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            return (data[5] == 'dokonané')
                ? true
                : false
        }     
    );
    table.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
});
//reset to default state
$("#filter1").click(function() {
     table.draw();
});
```

How can filter it by click on button with text `Buttons - filter`? I expecting equal filtering as button with text `Outside - filter`. (Buttons with text `Outside - reload` and `Buttons - reload` work well.)

Comment: `action` defines the function that will be called when button is clicked, you don't need to attach click handler as with outside buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom filter "inside" buttons too :

```
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
     function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        return data[5] == 'dokonané'
     }
   )     
   table.draw();
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hssLzgcg/**

Comment: $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop(); works for me! (re-filter independent)